# How many kinds of drivers are there?

Tags: device-driver, drivers

Like **device driver**， I don't know whether there are some **other drivers** ?

Comment: Cab drivers come to mind. And lorry drivers. :)

Comment: So far, all the answers are just taxonomizing device drivers.

Comment: @bmargulies If that's truly what you think, then it would seem that you would likely consider *any* driver to be a 'device driver'. All drivers, in a sense, are written to make the hardware do something useful...but there is a very dramatic difference between a Hardware Device Driver and, say, a File System Filter Driver.

Comment: @KevenK I consider all of these drivers to be device drivers. No one supplied any examples that answer the question: drivers that can't be called device drivers.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from Windows Internals 4th (XP-based) Edition:

**Hardware device drivers** - Drivers using the HAL
**File System Drivers** - File IO for devices
**File System Filter Drivers** - Intercept IO and do processing on it (like AV and such)
**Network Redirectors and Servers** - Transmit IO on the network
**Protocol Drivers** - Implement network protocol like TCP/IP
**Kernel Streaming Filter Drivers** - Signal processing on data streams like video/audio

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind straight away is [virtual device drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver#Virtual_device_drivers) - usually emulating some kind of device, but not being a device themselves.

Probably worth a mention is [class drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_driver) that can talk to an entire class of devices (e.g. USB).

And the Wikipedia [article on device drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) may be a good starting point.

Comment: upvoted for not being a wise-ass answer :P